# How to SPECIALIZE for a hsc2hs type?

Tags: haskell, ghc, hsc2hs

I'm trying to use the SPECIALIZE pragma to a type I get through hsc2hs's `#type`.

I tried something like this:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE someFn :: #{type DWORD} -> #{type DWORD} -> Bool #-}
someFn :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

That attempt fails with a `parse error on input '#'` (on the first `#{type DWORD}`).

I've put an answer that I found to work but I'm really hoping for something cleaner -- or more precisely: something that doesn't impact the entire module's code.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to delegate the `#type` using a `type` declaration:

```
type SDWORD = #{type DWORD}
{-# SPECIALIZE someFn :: SDWORD -> SDWORD -> Bool #-}
someFn :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```